# How can I trace ID/ParentID relationships among table rows?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, function

I have a table like `records(ID, ParentID)` containing this data:

```
ID   ParentID  
1    null  
2    1  
3    2   
4    2  
5    3  
6    null  
7    6
```

If you draw this table in hierarchy as a family, `1,2,3,4,5` will be related to each other.

I want to find a way to pass an ID (like `3`) such that it gives me the other family members. I'm using C# and SQL, either will do - I want to find a result like this:

```
3 - result 1,2,4,5
2 - result 1,3,4,5
6 - result 7
and so on
```

I want to find the parent of the ID I pass in, the grandparents, the children, and the grandchildren (as in my example).

Comment: How deep is the actual data? A CTE may do the job... When I've had to do this, though, I've just created a node-tree (as tables) manually, allowing me to query via `BETWEEN`

Comment: the depth of the data may be 3 or 4 levels

Comment: Do you have two rows with ID=3? I assume then that ID is not unique or identifying after all?

Comment: Is the test data representative of the full dataset?  For example, might there be some IDs that exist in ParentID but not in ID (e.g. 5).  Also, the test case for ID 2 doesn't match the description of what you want to find.  ID 2 has parent 1 and child 3 but 3 has no children so the result according to the description should be just 1,3, shouldn't it?

Comment: sorry "Daniel Renshaw", I edited my question , you are right,
now I hope it becomes clear

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ID int,
    ParentID int
)

INSERT #Test VALUES (1, null)
INSERT #Test VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT #Test VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT #Test VALUES (4, 2)
INSERT #Test VALUES (5, 3)
INSERT #Test VALUES (6, null)
INSERT #Test VALUES (7, 6)

DECLARE @QueryId int
SET @QueryId = 2

-- My parents
SELECT [ParentID] FROM #Test WHERE [ID] = @QueryID AND [ParentID] IS NOT NULL
UNION -- My parent's parents
SELECT [ParentID] FROM #Test WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT [ParentID] FROM #Test WHERE [ID] = @QueryID) AND [ParentID] IS NOT NULL
UNION -- My parent's children (i.e. my siblings), excluding me
SELECT [ID] FROM #Test WHERE [ParentID] IN (SELECT [ParentID] FROM #Test WHERE [ID] = @QueryID) AND [ID] != @QueryID
UNION -- My chidren
SELECT [ID] FROM #Test WHERE [ParentID] = @QueryId
UNION -- My chidren's children
SELECT [ID] FROM #Test WHERE [ParentID] IN (SELECT [ID] FROM #Test WHERE [ParentID] = @QueryId)

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: Another good solution, but it is only for 2 levels, if you set  @QueryId = 5 ,result is 2,3 where it should be 1,2,3,4 as 1,2,3 is in the tree of myParents and 4 come from one of my parents, Anyway thank You so much and thanks for all the members, I take the information I need from each of you all.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx) type which fits your problem seemingly well. Although this is only available with SQL Server 2008